# multiclient server that receives a file from few sources

Tags: python, sockets, select, networking, torrent

I'm building a torrent like program for a project. I want to get a file from few sources and then merge it together. the code below is my server and client for  the data transfer (note: in the main program these codes are threads). variables such as address, port, directories, filename, numofclients etc are just placeholders.
The problem I'm having is that half of the time, when a client connects, the server doesn't register him (meaning it doesn't give the client info it needs to continue the sending process). when this happens the client side claims its connected but I dont know if this issue is serverbased or clientbased. If anyone can help me find the issue that would be great, I've been trying to fix it for days.
Another side issue is that when the client does send the data, it send it significantly slower than when using a normal basic send loop with one client. is the select bottlenecking my speed?
note: I'm using python 2.7. prints are for monitoring.

server:

```
import random
import select
import socket
portnum=3500
filename="Testvid.avi"
numofclients=2
datalist=[]
for i in range(0,numofclients):
    datalist.append(open("C:/Users/Nitai/Desktop/Metorrent/"+filename+"-tmp"+str(i+1),'wb'))
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', portnum))
server_socket.listen(5)
s, address = server_socket.accept()
open_client_sockets = []
print "receivefile initiated"
def send_waiting_messages (wlist):
    for message in messages_to_send:
        (client_socket, data) = message
        if client_socket in wlist:
            client_socket.send(data)
            messages_to_send.remove(message)
messages_to_send = []
dataindex=0
socketindex=[]
finishedcount=0
while finishedcount<numofclients:
    rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select( [server_socket] + open_client_sockets,  open_client_sockets, [] )
    for current_socket in rlist:
        if current_socket is server_socket:
            print "new client"
            (new_socket,address)=server_socket.accept()
            open_client_sockets.append(new_socket)
            socketindex.append(new_socket)
            print open_client_sockets
            datatosend="IDP "+str(dataindex)+"%"+str(numofclients)
            print datatosend
            messages_to_send.append((new_socket,datatosend))
            print "data sent"
            print dataindex
            dataindex+=1
        else:
            data=current_socket.recv(1024)
            if data.find("EndPacket")!=-1:
                print "connection finished"
                finishedcount+=1
                open_client_sockets.remove(current_socket)
            else:
                datalist[socketindex.index(current_socket)].write(data)
    send_waiting_messages(wlist)
s.close()
print "select exited"
filewriter=open("C:/Users/Nitai/Desktop/Metorrent/"+filename+"-final",'wb')
for i in range(0,numofclients):
    filewriter.write(datalist[i].read())
print "File received"
filewriter.close()
print "transfer finished"
```

client:

```
import random
import socket
import os
portnum=3500
filename="Testvid.avi"
address='10.0.0.5'
s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((address, portnum))
print "connected"
data=s.recv(1024)
print "data received"
print data
index=int(data[4:data.find("%")])
print index
numofclients=int(data[data.find("%")+1:len(data)])
print numofclients
filetosend=open("C:/Users/Nitai/Desktop/"+filename,'rb')
filelength=int(os.stat("C:/Users/Nitai/Desktop/"+filename).st_size)
startpoint=(filelength/numofclients)*index
if numofclients==index+1:
    print "last part sender"
    endpoint=filelength
else:
    endpoint=(filelength/numofclients)*(index+1)
filetosend.seek(startpoint)
print startpoint
print endpoint
while startpoint+1024<endpoint:
    a=filetosend.read(1024)
    s.send(a)
    startpoint+=1024
l=filetosend.read(endpoint-filetosend.tell())
s.send(l)
filetosend.close()
time.sleep(3)
endpacketdata="EndPacket"
s.send(endpacketdata)
print "File sent"
s.close()
print "data transfer complete"
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

After the `server_socket.listen(5)`, you have `s, address = server_socket.accept()` which is out of place, since the `accept` is to be done in the `while` loop.